# Infer `K extends keyof T` in typescript, not just `any` or `keyof T`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing some lens functions:

```
interface Lens<C, V> = {
  get: (container: C) => V;
  set: (container: C, value: V) => C;
}

interface Container {
  value: number;
  other: string;
};

const valueLens: Lens<Container, number> = {
  get: (container: Container) => container.value,
  set: (container: Container, value: number): Container => ({ ...container, value }),
};
```

The pattern for simple field lenses is extremely obvious, so I wanted to abstract it:

```
function makeFieldLens<T, K extends keyof T>(key: K): Lens<T, T[K]> {
  return {
    get: (container: T): T[K] => container[key],
    set: (container: T, value: T[K]): T => ({ ...container, [key]: value }),
  };
}
```

But because you can't partially specify templates, you need to specify both `T` and `K` in the generic type parameters, which becomes very cumbersome and repetitive:

```
const valueLens = makeFieldLens<Container, 'value'>('value');
const value: number = valueLens.get(container);
```

I tried to find a way to infer `K extends keyof T`:

Providing a default type of `key` for the compiler just sets `typeof key` as `'value' | 'other'`, which means the return type of `get` is `number | string` not just `number`:

```
function makeFieldLens<T, K = keyof T>(key: K): Lens<T, T[K]> {
  return {
    get: (container: T): T[K] => container[key],
    set: (container: T, value: T[K]): T => ({ ...container, [key]: value }),
  };
}

// This won't typecheck, because the return is `number | string` not `number`.
const valueLens = makeFieldLens<Container>('value');
const value: number = valueLens.get(container);
```

Ommiting the type of `key` for the compiler to derive just infers `typeof key` as `any`, and the return type of `get` as `any` as well not jut `number`:

```
function makeFieldLens<T>(key): Lens<T, T[typeof key]> {
  return {
    get: (container: T): T[typeof key] => container[key],
    set: (container: T, value: T[typeof key]): T => ({ ...container, [key]: value }),
  };
}

const valueLens = makeFieldLens<Container, 'value'>('value');
const value: number = valueLens.get(container);

// This won't fail, because the return type is `any` not `string`.
const otherLens = makeFieldLens<Container>('other');
const other: number = otherLens.get(container);
```

The typescript lens library puts the key method in a class:

```
class Lens<T>
{
  makeFieldLens: <K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K];
}
```

But that's no use because I don't have an outer class.  I experimented with psudo-replicating it, but couldn't get an instantiation of the following:

```
interface FieldLens<T> {
  <K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K];
};
```

I tried using a second function, infering the types for the first and passing them explicitly to the second:

```
function keyLensInternal<T, K extends keyof T>(key: K): Lens<T, T[K]> {
  return {
    get_: (container: T): T[K] => container[key],
    set_: (container: T) => (value: AddDateString<NonNullable<T[K]>>): T => ({ ...container, [key]: value }),
  };
}

export function keyLens<T>(key) {
  return keyLensInternal<T, typeof key>(key);
}
```

That still inferred `any` as the return type, and getting very clever with the types didn't compile:

```
export function keyLens<T>(key): ReturnType<typeof (keyLensInternal<T, typeof key>)> {
  return keyLensInternal<T, typeof key>(key);
}
```

The basic problem is that most solutions infer `any` or `keyof T`, rather than `K extends keyof T` to isolate just one key.  Is there any other way to do this keeping a nice API?  I don't mind specifying `<T>` (in fact doing so is a requirement), but I want `K` inferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "curried function" to split generic parameters (so the first one can be specified explicitly and the second one inferred):

```
const makeFieldLens = <T>() => <K extends keyof T>(key: K): Lens<T, T[K]> => ({
  get: (container: T): T[K] => container[key],
  set: (container: T, value: T[K]): T => ({ ...container, [key]: value }),
});

const valueLens = makeFieldLens<Container>()('value');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIRAZwDwGEA0yAagHzIDeAUMsgOYRgBcyAFAgPbhyjTO4CUyALxkiAbmrJMDZm05huIXsgLIAbnAA2AVwjMigkSokBfSpVCRYiFLnmLoFSRp17kIbQFsARtAk12MAALZUwwKFBaUwlKDiwwZE84AGsIADFgCE0AE3QsYWRsABUSFkMybABpZAgAD0gQbMxkVIBPdhhkEpY25kr%20ZjycIsIigG1KgF0yIxYqGnomVjiFHihmIoGuicnhMhWHKDG2yfxJaSW5LjWNwhddDZ2tor3WcmQAOi%20DtcJjiFak2Y9xQJn4ZzBMWyEAQmjgUBQcTCyB%20SnWKnsaxiSISIKGBSSqQyWVyGBwdmuaNK-BYAHIQbT%20BIceotA93F5fFACniyR9FldVmimUA)